# Extendable or programmable mail server

Tags: email

Is there any extendable mail server that can implement a service like a chat robot?

I think what I am looking for is a middleware based on SMTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this library and it provides exactly what I need.

https://code.google.com/p/subethasmtp/

Answer (score 0):

Most unix MTAs can do that. One way is to make a login called foo so that you have an email address foo@example.org. Then you put `|/home/foo/program` into `/home/foo/.forward`. Now /home/foo/program will be invoked on each incoming mail, receiving the message content as input.

There's a program called formail which may be quite handy (if you write in sh).

Comment: Thank you for your help! But I need add/delete email accounts dynamically, so I don't want to use system users as email accounts.I found a java library called [subethamail](https://code.google.com/p/subethasmtp/).

Comment: How nice to see someone who asks, considers the answer, and then goes off to find a better approach. That's so much better than "plz can u write my code for me".